# Allow Standard user to run program requiring UAC elevation

Tags: windows-7, uac, elevation, standard-user

I need a standard or limited Windows 7 user to be able to run an application (Fallout Mod Manager) which requires UAC elevation. I've tried the Application Compatibilty Toolkit, but that did not work as intended. Any Suggestions? I am running Windows 7 Ultimate local, so policies can be applied.

I basically want something like unix' setuid flag.

Comment: When you can the toolkit did you click 'Change settings for all users'?

Comment: I've used sdbinstall to deploy the changes, and I went through MSDN/Technet docs. asAdmin or asHighest don't work because they do trigger the promt, and asInvoker won't work because it does need the priviliges

Comment: Have you been able to figure out why the application is requiring elevation? If it needs read/write access to certain folders, for example, you might be able to solve that by changing NTFS permissions.

Comment: @nhinkle memory hook (on the fallout process. (Fallout Script Extender))

Comment: The user can run the program, but will have to enter the credentials of an administrator account when UAC prompts for elevation. If that's not a satisfactory solution, unfortunately I don't know enough to help any further. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's doable, but not easy to explain.

There are only three reasons why an application would request for elevation on startup:

- the **Compatibilty** tab has the "Run this program as an administrator"
- the application has a manifest (either embedded or external) that specified `requireAdministrator`
- there is a compatibility update from Microsoft that marked it as needed administrator

Assuming you've already checked the compatibility tab, and the application is **not** set to require administrator:

[image]

The next step is to check for an embedded resource manifest. i won't go into how you can find that out. But skip to create a manifest for yourself.

Create a file in the same directory as Fallout Mod Manager (i don't know what the `exe` is called, but i'll call it `FalloutModManager.exe`:

FalloutModManager.exe
   FalloutModManager.exe.manifest

This new `manifest` file you create is a simple text file, containing xml, with a manifest entry that says that we want to launch **asInvoker**, rather than **requireAdministrator**:

**FalloutModManager.exe.manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
      <assemblyIdentity 
           version="1.0.0.0"
           processorArchitecture="X86"
           name="client"
           type="win32" /> 

      <description>Poorly written Fallout Mod Manager fails on XP as standard user</description> 

      <!-- Disable file and registry virtualization, and don't require elevation -->
      <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
         <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
               <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
         </security>
      </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Having this file *next to* your executable is called an "*external manifest*". It is also possible the executable has an embedded resource, which you would need a tool like Resource Hacker to see, or modify.

Comment: Won't creating a manifest saying don't run a admin only work if the program is incorrectly manifested; but fail if the program is actually doing something that requires elevation?  (The memory hook.)

Comment: If there is an internal manifest, it will take prescidence over an external manifest. In that you you should edit the internal manfiest to specify `asInvoker`. If the program is doing something that requires administrator access then it will fail - but then it would also fail on Windows XP with a standard user. There are a number of workaround that Microsoft added to try to fix buggy applications that fail as standard user. But the best bet is: If you want all users to be able to modify `HKLM` and `ProgramFiles`, then grant **All Users** full permission to `HKLM` and `ProgramFiles`.

Comment: I'm afraid @DanNeely is right, and that this won't work. FOMM tries to insert it's own DLLs into a different exectuable (Fallout3.exe)

Comment: i'm sure there are things FOMM can do that don't require administrative access. By marking the executable `asInvoker` you will no longer have to elevate in order to run the program. You might not be able to accomplish all you want - but at least now you can run the executable as a regular user.

Comment: What if you copied Fallout3.exe into a folder outside of %Program Files%, had FOMM modify the copy, and then launch Fallout using that exe instead of the one inside %Program Files% ?